# Laravel : Class controller does not exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have created a simple controller and define a function. But when i run this it returns an error that controller does not exist.

In my web.php assign a route.

```
<?php
  Route::get('/', function () { return view('front.welcome'); });
  Route::get('plan','PlanController@PlanActivity')->name('plan');
```

On otherside in my controller my code:

```
<?php
 namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;
 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlanController extends Controller {

public function PlanActivity()
{
    dd("hello");
    //return view('admin.index');
}
}
```

> This controller created on App\Http\Controllers\Front - on front folder

Error :

> ReflectionException (-1)
>   Class App\Http\Controllers\PlanController does not exist

Comment: `Route::get('plan','Front\PlanController@PlanActivity')->name('plan');`

Comment: @javed remove this line it not needed  use App\Http\Controllers\Controller as BaseController;

Comment: @javed check you namespace in controller and folder name matching or not

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `Front` part to:

```
Route::get('plan', 'Front\PlanController@PlanActivity')->name('plan');
```

Also, change the top of the controller to:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

And run `composer du`.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-namespaces):

> By default, the `RouteServiceProvider` includes your route files within a namespace group, allowing you to register controller routes without specifying the full `App\Http\Controllers` namespace prefix. So, you only need to specify the portion of the namespace that comes after the base `App\Http\Controllers` namespace.

Comment: So is it ok to define in controller `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Front;`

Answer (score 0):

First when defining route, make sure to use the correct path for the controller. the correct is:

```
Route::get('plan','Front/PlanController@PlanActivity')->name('plan');
```

Second you have imported `Controller` Class as `BaseController`. so you should extends  `BaseController` not `Controller`:

```
class PlanController extends BaseController {

public function PlanActivity()
{
    dd("hello");
    //return view('admin.index');
}
}
```

Comment: It's funny how Leo copied the wrong code from my answer and you've copied the wrong code from his answer.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin don't worry we know you are number one user in so for laravel! We learn from you.

Comment: @Alexey At the time i was writing my answer, Your answer was not published. I just copied some text from the question.