# Target class does not exist. - Laravel

Tags: laravel

Im trying to make a little crud.

Current I have this issue where it doesnt recongize my controller which I have.

Error:

> Target class [App\Http\Controllers\CRUD\ProductController] does not exist.

web.php

```
Route::get('/CRUD', 'CRUD\ProductController@index');
```

Controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $products = Products::index();
        dd($products);
        return view("CRUD.view", [ "products" => $products]);
    }
}
```

[image: My file directory]

Comment: please, attach your file structure

Comment: @V-K I've editted it in.

Comment: ok, run `composer dump-autoload` in the console

Comment: @V-K donezo, still get the same error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel : Class controller does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48617556/laravel-class-controller-does-not-exist)

Comment: Question is specific to his case, but this is a common Laravel error message and there's a good answer posted.

Comment: I solved this problem this way from another post:
[Solution way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450296)

Comment: I solved this issue this way from another post:[Solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65450296)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the ProductController file namespace, it should look like:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\CRUD;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index ()
    {
        $products = Products::index();
        dd($products);
        return view("CRUD.view", [ "products" => $products]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `namespace App\Http\Controllers;` this is the only namespace in ProductController.

Comment: @Tim the namespace must be the same as that you're using in the code (it seems like you want to add "CRUD" to the namespace, so you can add it to this line). It should also follow your file path.

Answer (score 6):

Check the file `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` and uncomment the line:

```
 protected $namespace = 'App\Http\\Controllers';
```

Then clean the cache: php artisan route:cache

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer actually.

Answer (score 0):

should follow above comment check file **app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php**

> and uncomment the line: **protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';**